# Most idiomatic way to iterate through and add to set functionally

Tags: scala, immutability, gremlin, immutable-collections

I'm using Gremlin to iterate through a `GraphTraversal` object and retrieve the vertices.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
def getVertexSet(vIter: GraphTraversal[Vertex, Vertex]): Set[Vertex] = {
  val s = mutable.HashSet.empty[Vertex]
  vIter.forEachRemaining(v => s.add(v))
  s.toSet
}
```

I'd like to be able to do this without converting from a mutable collection to an immutable collection. I don't know if that's possible with an iterator. The Scala way to do this is probably using tail recursion but I'm not sure there's any performance benefit to that and at that point, a single conversion to immutable at the end is probably more readable anyways.

Also, if there's a better way to collect all the vertices from a traversal, I'm open to that optimization as well.

Comment: `GraphTraversal` implements `java.util.Iterator`, answer from @Markus exploits that fact very nicely. If you only had to rely on `forEachRemaining`, than using a temporary mutable collection is perfectly justified. After all, this method returns `void` and accepts only a `Consumer` as the argument (another `void`). You are pretty much forced to go mutable, at least in a local scope of 3 lines, which is fine.

Comment: @ygor you're right. Scala does give you the possibility to keep your code functional, but internally it will do the same mutable operations you already do anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are okay with using Scala's `Set` instead of Java's, go with:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._

def getVertexSet(vIter: GraphTraversal[Vertex, Vertex]): Set[Vertex] = {
    vIter.asInstanceOf[java.util.Iterator[Vertex]].asScala.toSet
}
```

[Try it out!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/mwf6VZ8/1)

You can still call `.asJava` on the `Set[Vertex]` later on if you really need a Java `Set`.

Comment: Is the explicit casting to `java.util.Iterator` necessary? It seems to be working without the cast, at least in the ScalaFiddle.

Comment: It depends, it seems like `GraphTraversal` extends a number of interfaces. There might be multiple ones that hava a `.toScala`. If you try it out and it works anyways, then drop it. The ScalaFiddle mocks `GraphTraversal`, extending only the `Iterator`. That's why it works without.

Comment: Ok, next observation: Is `forEachRemaining` functionally equivalent to iterating using `hasNext` and `next`? Disclaimer: I already upvoted your answer .. but I am just curious.

Comment: I think `forEachRemaining` can very well be implemented using `next` and `hasNext`. I will check. Also, don't forget to accept the answer if you want. :)

Comment: I checked [here](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/Traversal.java), and I can confirm, `forEachRemaining` does use `next` internally.